# Dependency cycle detected

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, splines

Older user of 3ds Max, I am a new user of blender. A friend introduced me to your forum to ask my questions. I'm delighted to be here.

On this moment, I'm trying to learn the rigging on blender and I have a problem de dependency. I looked for an answer to my questions but I do not find. The subject closest to mine I found is this one, [Rigging question about Spline IK and having all controls on one armature](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35398/rigging-question-about-spline-ik-and-having-all-controls-on-one-armature), but it does not work in my case either.

Indeed, I want rig a bird. To make the rig of the feathers of the wings I have a bezierCurve drived by bones controller with the hook modifier. The bezierCurve drive many empty with a follow path modifier. Each feather have a "track to" modifier to an empty. In 3ds Max, no problem with this rig. In blender like the armature is a single object and it's impossible to add a beziercurve in the armature I have a problem of dependency:

Dependency cycle detected:
  BezierCurve depends on Armature through Hook Modifier.
  Armature depends on BezierCurve through Spline IK.

The only solution I have find is to create two armatures. One armature with the "track to" bone system and the second armature with the bones with the hook modifier. But this system it's not practice because i have two armature to control the rig :/

Do you have a solution to this kind of problem? that it will be the best method?

Many thanks by advance.

Ludovic Habas

Comment: Hi, there really is no easy solution other than 2 armatures in Blender, in blender the dependency handling is inferior to 3ds max and is not solved on bone level, but sadly on object level only (on bone level only inside armature data structure). If you really really want to have all in one armature, you will have to build your own spline chain from bones and spline math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline. It is rather complicated, uses lots of constraints which impacts performance and does not bring much usability over the 2 armature solution.

Comment: Could work something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4SyQ.gif. I have scripts to generate this, but cannot share them yet unfortunately. Can be done through drivers and constraints only, no *app.handlers* or *pydrivers*. It is exactly like bendy bones (Bbones), but you can parent stuff to individual segments or even custom drive the segments yourself.

Comment: I barely understand what you're trying, due to my poor rigging skills, but if you could strip down your rig to a minimum example file, someone could provide an alternative, maybe. If so, share it using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then post the provided link in your post.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot. You explication is very cleary Jerryno. I will try to make my spline with math or use two armature.

Comment: @LudovicHabas see my answer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87656/is-this-actually-a-dependency-cycle/87658#87658, the dependency graph is being fixed, and you can already experiment with some of the fixes.